# usages of virtual and new

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, virtual, new-operator

As far as i see in c#,

virtual function are not just for polymorphism,

it is also for overriding the hiding method warning by the compiler

am i right ?

i will give an example :

```
class A
{
   public void func(int a)
     {
        ....
     }
}
class B:A
{
   public void func(int a)
     {
        ....
     }
}
```

now , im using `B x = new B();`
so the compiler will warn me for method in class B hides the one in A.
so there is 2 solutions :

1) mark the one in B with the `New` keyword

2)  make the one in `'A' virtual` and the one in `B - Overriding` - this will clear the warning of hiding..

the only difference will be with **Polymorphism** `A x = new B();`

if there will be **'new'** in class B - always the one from A will be called while if im using the `virtual` and **not** the new mechanism - the one from B will be called.

so virtual has 2 roles in .net :  (please **correct** me if im wrong)

**1)** resolve the hiding warning (in **non-Polymorphism enviroment**)

**2)** and of course overriding the functions in **yes-polymorphism enviroment**.

please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with ASP.NET in particular?

Comment: You should learn the difference between overloading and overriding

Comment: i know , just i was typing very quickly and wasnt  paying attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, virtual methods *are* for polymorphism. Your "solution" #2 will change the behaviour of calling `x.func()` from calling the A implementation to calling the B implementation - i.e. making it polymorphic. Yes, it removes the warning - but it's no longer a "non-polymorphism environment" as you've made the behaviour polymorphic. Did you want to do that, or not? If you did, then `virtual` and `override` is the way to go. If you didn't, you should use `new` or rename the method.

I would *strongly* advise you to avoid using method hiding unless you really need to. Do you even need `B` to derive from `A`? If you want to give it another method with the same name but a different meaning, consider making them separate classes. Personally I steer away from inheritance unless there's a clear polymorphic relationship.

(Note that overriding and overloading are different concepts, by the way. You mean overriding here.)

Comment: if im using the virtual  & overload ,  and executing : B x = new B() - i didnt use any polymorphic  command like A = new B() - and still hide the warning...

Comment: @Mid787: override, not overload. But you've still introduced polymorphism into it... anyone who *does* write `A x = new B();` will see that polymorphic behaviour. As far as the classes A and B are concerned, it's a polymorphic call. If you don't want polymorphism, either remove the inheritance relationship or rename the method.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler warning is just that. It's a warning that your implementation of func() is *probably* incorrect, because it's hiding the member form the base class.

It's effect is to remove the warning, but that's not its reason. The *reason* is to make you double-check and confirm your intention.

Answer (score 0):

Basically "New" keyword  is used to overcome the warning of hiding method.
while virtual key word is purely for the polymorphism it tells the compiler if override version of the method available then run that method other wise run virtual method.

Virtual overriding is also called runtime polymorphism.because it decides on runtime that what method will be run.

While "New" keyword remove the warning and only run child class method and hides the parent method ,so to over come this we use:

```
   public new void Method()
{
//Some code
Base.Method();

}
```

by using this we run parent method and unhide the parent class method

Comment: if im using the virtual & overload , and executing : B x = new B() - i didnt use any polymorphic command like A = new B() - and still hide the warning...

Comment: yes offcourse,because compiler understand that there is no hiding in that syntax.In simple words.The only place where you need to use "new" is when the method is not related in any way to the base class version.This good link to read
http://blog.colinmackay.net/archive/2008/10/10/4264.aspx